# Get scope of a @ManagedBean in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, javabeans, cdi, managed-bean

I am currently hacking on a project where a base class is extended by a lot of beans.

There is a common method on this base class and basically the only change I need to do is to check if when a particular invocation fails the current instance invoking the method is an application scoped bean. If it is, I just have to log the error message and return a cached response; if it is not, I have to raise an exception.

Appart from using `instanceof` on every application scoped bean extending this base class, is there any way to know if the object `this` is an Application scoped bean?

Comment: If the bean is stored in `ServletContext`, then it's application scoped, otherwise it isn't.

Comment: You might need to flesh out your scenario clearly - CDI provides a robust bean metadata lookup mechanism; or you could just do the context lookup like @LuiggiMendoza recommends - depends on your scenario and how "clean" you want it to look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether the class of some instance has particular annotations. For example, the call:

```
Annotation[] annotations = this.getClass().getAnnotations();
```

will give you all annotations of current instance. Or you may want to find out some certain annotation:

```
ApplicationScoped annotation = this.getClass().getAnnotation(ApplicationScoped.class);
```

which will return `null` if class isn't annotated with `@ApplicationScoped`

In case of inheritance, the method `getAnnotations()` returns annotations of a parent class too and annotated with `@RequestScoped` class will return also an `@ApplicationScoped` if its parent was declared so. On the other hand, JSF-managed beans will override the parent's scope.

Hope this helps you.